When I Upload an Excel File In Collab, It Keeps Reading the First Line of the Table as NaN
I am trying to read excel files on Google Collab, but for some reason it always reads the first line as being filled empty.
It does not do this every time and with every file, despite the formatting always being the same and generated from the same source.
Thus far, this only seems to happen unless I open the document and manually re-save it or change it in some way.
Once I do, it's fine.
Does anyone know why this is happening?
Code:
import pandas as pd
import io
from google.colab import files


print("Choose report to upload")
userreport = files.upload()


filename_dep=[key for key in userreport.keys()][0]


#ignores the first couple of lines that are unimportant
df4 = pd.read_excel(filename_dep, header=[6], dtype='object')

df4


Example of Table
Code and NaN Result

"What is going wrong?" -> how could we know without debugging details? We don't have access to your files, nor the code used to load the data. NB. images of code/data are not reproducible. [ask] / [mre].
